# MP4/AVI videos are not playing on safari browser : Django 2

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, safari, mp4

I create one web application using django 2.1 and python3 and in my requirements is upload video and play video and its absolutely working excellent dynamically and static in all browser except safari browser

I have already tried everything in html tag (video,autoplay,muted,loop playsinline,controls,type="video/mp4",codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2") etc... everything but still not playing video in safari browser.

my all python logic view + model files code is perfect and working and getting excellent output in all browser except safari browser.

I have already checked all inspect elements and path,all videos path are placed in right place.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left-video-div">
        <video autoplay muted loop playsinline controls width="320" height="240" class="video-background ">
              <source src="{% static "sample_test01.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video autoplay muted loop playsinline controls width="320" height="240" class="video-background ">
              <source src="{% static "sample_test02.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video autoplay muted loop playsinline controls width="320" height="240" class="video-background ">
              <source src="{% static "sample_test03.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video autoplay muted loop playsinline controls width="320" height="240" class="video-background ">
              <source src="/media/static/clips/userid_420/2019-07-15_182035.991933_Test_Video_02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The video tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output all static and dynamic video playing in safari browser.

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'